# Утечка памяти в C++

Tags: память, строки, c++

Есть проблемы с утчкой памяти в C++.
У меня есть функция такого вида

```
WCHAR* getLongName()
{
WCHAR* longname = new WCHAR[n];
..............................
return longname;
}
```

При вызове функции происходит утечка памяти, причем в строке delete[] вылетает ошибка.

```
WCHAR* str=getLongName();
delete[] str;
```

Как это можно исправить?
Полный текст функции

```
WCHAR* Record::getLongName()
{
WCHAR* in=getName();
int k=0;
for (int i=0;i<11;i++)
{
    if(in[i]!=' ') k++;
}
if(k>=11) return in;
WCHAR *res=new WCHAR[k+1];
ZeroMemory(res,sizeof(WCHAR)*(k+1));
bool f=true;
for(WCHAR* a=in,*b=res;*a;++a,++b)
{
    while(*a==' ') 
        {
            if(f) {*b='.';b++;f=false;}
            ++a;
        }
        *b=*a;
}
delete[] in;
res[k+1]='\0';
return res;
}
```

Comment: я воспроизвел в таком объеме код. Утечек нет. Скорее всего у Вас где то происходит порча памяти. Нужно больше кода.

Comment: Ну да ступил, забываю C++ потихоньку))) Присоединяюсь к @KoVadim, нуден более полный код ф-и getLongName() и ошибки и предупреждения компилятора

Comment: память нужно удалять в пределах функции. имхо проблем будет меньше. пересморите логику. @KoVadim видимо разные компиляторы ведут себя по разному. @Павел Воевода проверте не записасали ли вы за предел массива

Comment: @KoVadim, ошибка такая "heap corruption detected after normal block. crt detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer"

Comment: ошибку правильно говорит - порча памяти, даже точно указывает - запись за пределы массива. Подозреваю, что это все внутри двойного цикла и происходит. Повреждает массив `res` (он же `b`). Предлагаю просто написать на с++ этот код, а не на с+. Расскажите, что должен делать этот код (и пару примеров входных и выходных данных).

Comment: Подозрительно выглядит вся программа, про сторку 

     res[k+1]='\0';

которая пишет вне res, уже и говорить не стоит. in проверяется для вычисления k до 11, а в цикле переноса из in в res -- пока *a != 0. Сложно всё

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Элемента с индексом **k+1** в массиве **res** не существует. Последний элемент имеет индекс **k**. В 3-й с конца кода строке выход за пределы массива.

Answer (score 5):

Вообще код комментировать не буду, там как-то все достаточно опасно =)

Ошибка здесь:

```
WCHAR *res=new WCHAR[k+1];
...
res[k+1]='\0';
```

Вы присваиваете значение зеро-терминатора следующему после буфера сегменту памяти (у нас массивы нумеруются с нуля, тобишь, крайний элемент - это `res[кол-во элементов-1]`).

**UPD**: Опоздал))